# Unbound Error Python Class

Tags: python, class, static

I have researched everywhere and although I find the same concepts, I cannot seem to find an answer to my error.

I did not post before because my account info was forgotten on stack, but I have grown very frustrated with this beginner's error.

```
class Person(object):

    def __init__(self, name, phone):
        self.name = name
        self.phone = phone

class Employee(Person):

    total_salary = 0

    @staticmethod
    def total_salary(self, salary):
        return total_salary


    def __init__(self, name, phone, salary):
        self.name = name
        self.phone = phone
        self.salary = salary




class Student(Person):

    def __init__(self, name, phone, gpa):
        self.gpa = gpa
        self.name = name
        self.phone = phone

    def __str__(self):
        reply = ""
        reply = "Person " + self.name + " has phone " + self.phone + "\n" + " and is a Student with gpa " + str(self.gpa)
        return reply

class Professor(Employee):
    def __init__(self, name, phone, salary, clas_teach):
        self.clas_teach = clas_teach
        self.name = name
        self.phone = phone
        self.salary = salary

    def __str__(self):
        reply = ""
        reply = "Person " + self.name + " has phone " + self.phone + "\n" + " and is an Employee with salary " + str(self.salary) + "\n"
        reply += " and is a Professor assigned to class " + self.clas_teach
        return reply

class Staff(Employee):
    def __init__(self, name, phone, salary, position):
        self.position = position
        self.name = name
        self.phone = phone
        self.salary = salary
    def __str__(self):
        reply = ""
        reply = "Person " + self.name + " has phone " + self.phone + "\n" + " and is an Employee with salary " + str(self.salary) + "\n"
        reply += " and is Staff with title " + self.position
        return reply
# Create a list of people
People = [ Student("Sandy", "326-8324", 3.65), Student("Jordan", "632-7434", 3.1), \
           Professor("Leslie", "985-2363", 50000.00, "Info 501"),  \
           Staff("Alex", "743-4638", 25000.00, "Editor") ]

# display information about our people
print "These are the people in the university:"
for person in People:
   print person

# display the total salaries of all our employees and average GPA
#  of all of our students
print
print "Our total university payroll budget is: " + str(Employee.total_salary)
print "Our average student GPA is: " + str(Student.mean_gpa())
```

Comment: The error is now <function total_salary at 0x02682670> but without the @staticmethod it gave me <unbound method Employee.total_salary>

Comment: You never sum the salaries in the total_salaries method, you pass two parameters that are not used and the `total_salary` is a class attribute that is not used as well, other than being returned. What are you trying to do? How do you want to solve this issue?

Comment: I am trying to add the salaries of the employees in People, but also want to make sure it adds the salaries if I add an employee

Comment: Don't you think you need another class, say, `University` which has an attribute named something like: `people`, which is a list of Person, and then you have the `total_personel_budget` method there, which goes through all the people and adds the salary if they are an employee.

Comment: `@staticmethod` and `self` in the function definition is very likely wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Your main misunderstanding is how classes work. In your code, you are calling classes rather than instances of classes:

```
print "Our total university payroll budget is: " + str(Employee.total_salary)
print "Our average student GPA is: " + str(Student.mean_gpa())
```

The key thing here is:

```
Employee.total_salary
```

Instead you should be doing something like this:

```
leslie = Professor("Leslie", "985-2363", 50000.00, "Info 501")
print "Leslie's Salary: " + str(leslie.salary)
```

For this specific case, you want the total payroll, which is the sum of all employee salaries. You need a collection of employees somewhere.

```
def University():
    def __init__(self):
        self.employees[]

    def add_employee(self, employee):
        self.employees.append(employee)

    def get_total_payroll(self):
        total = 0
        for employee in self.employees:
            total += employee.salary
        return total
```

then use an instance of that class:

```
university = University()
university.add_employee(Professor("Leslie", "985-2363", 50000.00, "Info 501"))
university.add_employee(Staff("Alex", "743-4638", 25000.00, "Editor"))

print "Total payroll: " + str(university.get_total_payroll())
```

Obviously, there are a lot more adjustments you need to make, like sorting betweeen employees and students, etc. But hopefully this is enough to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

There are problems with your overall design that have been covered in other answers, so I will just try to explain why your current code is not working:

1. You have created a class attribute named `total_salary`, and then shadowed it with a method of the same name.
2. You are using a static method, when you need to use a class method.
3. You need to call `total_salary` as a method in order to return its value.

These problems can be fixed like this:

```
class Employee(Person):
    _total_salary = 0

    @classmethod
    def total_salary(cls):
        return cls._total_salary
...

print "Our total university payroll budget is: " + str(Employee.total_salary())
```

But note that the code will still raise an `AttributeError`, because you are trying to call `Student.mean_gpa`, which hasn't been defined yet.

Answer (score 0):

Your class Employee has an attribute AND a method with the same name. Calling Employee.total_salary will return the function because in the `MRO` it's replacing the attribute.

Change:

```
class Employee(Person):
    total_salary = 0
```

to

```
class Employee(Person):
    total_salary_value = 0
```

Your `staticmethod total_salary` in `Employee` is returning a variable that doesn't exist(because it's looking only in the method scope), you should return the Employee.total_salary_value. Like so:

```
@staticmethod
def total_salary():
    return Employee.total_salary_value
```

In the `__init__` of `Employee` you are not instantiating the `Person` that you are inheriting (the same thing in `Student`(inheriting `Person`), `Professor` and `Staff`(both inheriting `Employee`)

Use either:

```
Person.__init__(self,name,phone)
```

or

```
super(Employee, self).__init__(name, phone)
```

Still in the init, you are not adding the salary to the `total_salary_value`

add this:

```
Employee.total_salary_value += self.salary
```

Also, there's no need to use `self.name` and `self.phone` in the `Student`, because `Person` already has this attribute. (The same for that and other variables in `Professor` and `Staff`)

And lastly, `Student` doesn't have a method called `mean_gpa`. You have to implement it.

Here's the code:

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, name, phone):
        self.name = name
        self.phone = phone

class Employee(Person):
    total_salary_value = 0

    @classmethod
    def total_salary(cls):
        return cls.total_salary_value

    def __init__(self, name, phone, salary):
        Person.__init__(self,name,phone)
        self.salary = salary
        Employee.total_salary_value += self.salary

class Student(Person):
    all_gpa = []

    def __init__(self, name, phone, gpa):
        Person.__init__(self,name,phone)
        self.gpa = gpa
        Student.all_gpa.append(self.gpa)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Person {0} has phone {1} and is a Student with gpa {2}".format(self.name,self.phone,self.gpa)

    @classmethod
    def mean_gpa(cls):
        return sum(cls.all_gpa)/len(cls.all_gpa)


class Professor(Employee):
    def __init__(self, name, phone, salary, clas_teach):
        Employee.__init__(self,name,phone,salary)
        self.clas_teach = clas_teach

    def __str__(self):
        return "Person {0} has phone {1} and is an Employee with salary {2}\n" \
               "and is a Professor assigned to class {3}".format(self.name,self.phone,self.salary,self.clas_teach)


class Staff(Employee):
    def __init__(self, name, phone, salary, position):
        Employee.__init__(self, name, phone, salary)
        self.position = position

    def __str__(self):
        return "Person {0} has phone {1} and is an Employee with salary {2}\n" \
               "and is Staff with title {3}".format(self.name, self.phone, self.salary, self.position)

# Create a list of people
People = [ Student("Sandy", "326-8324", 3.65),
           Student("Jordan", "632-7434", 3.1),
           Professor("Leslie", "985-2363", 50000.00, "Info 501"),
           Staff("Alex", "743-4638", 25000.00, "Editor") ]

# display information about our people
print "These are the people in the university:"
for person in People:
   print person

# display the total salaries of all our employees and average GPA
#  of all of our students
print
print "Our total university payroll budget is: " + str(Employee.total_salary())
print "Our average student GPA is: " + str(Student.mean_gpa())
```

EDIT:

As @ekhumoro said, it's better to use a @classmethod to return the value.

Another thing, your `__str__` could be made more clear using .format()